# Отфильтровать DataFrame по известным значениям в нескольких столбцах другого DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Есть `DataFrame` типа

```
   key  category quantity  amount  values
0 a01    good       3        1       0
1 a02    good       2        2       1
2 a03    good       1        1       0
3 a03   broken      2        1       4
4 a01    good       5        1       1
```

И второй `DataFrame` типа

```
   key  category  amount
0 a01    good       3     
1 a02    good       2      
2 a03    good       1
```

Как отфильтровать первый `DataFrame` по второму таким образом, чтобы в первом остались все столбцы, но строки только те, в которых значения совпадают в нужных столбцах со вторым `DataFrame`? Т.е. иными словами второй `DataFrame` содержит набор уникальных значений (конкретный `amount` для данной `category` для определённого `key`), по которым мне нужно отфильтровать первый, сохранив все его строки с такими значениями и данные в других столбцах. На выходе должно быть:

```
   key  category quantity  amount  values
0 a01    good       3        3       0
1 a02    good       2        2       1
2 a03    good       1        1       0
3 a03    good       3        1       5
4 a02    good       2        2       2
5 a03    good       1        1       4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте merge. Для приведенных вами примеров:

```
res = pd.merge(df1, df2, how="inner", on=["category", "amount", "key"])
```

res будет:

```
   key category  quantity  amount  values
0  a02     good         2       2       1
1  a03     good         1       1       0
```

Comment: Спасибо! Из документации не смог понять, что можно делать merge не только по 1 колонке.